# Joining on a column where the value can be NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to unary join a table using an ID which can be NULL (here it's MID). Here's my code so far (names shortened for convenience):

```
SELECT s1.SName, s2.SName
FROM S s1
JOIN S s2 ON s1.MID = s2.SID
```

I'm unsure how to get this query to return all rows, regardless of whether or not MID is NULL. I've tried a few different things but I think my lack of understanding or experience is the fundamental problem here.

Comment: When s1.MID is NULL, what value should be shown for s1.SName?  And do you want it to match s2.SID being NULL?  Give us a short sample of data and show us what the result should be.  (Be sure to include all possible NULL/non-null cases.)

Comment: @RickJames s1.SName should show a name regardless of whether s1.MID is NULL. I don't want it to match s2.SID being NULL; I'm aware that using = isn't correct here, just using it as a baseline.
So for example, if there's 2 rows - I'm formatting them as (SID, SName, MID) here - (S01, Victor, NULL) & (S02, Leah, S01), I want both Victor & Leah to be displayed along with their associated MIDs, which only Leah has in this case.

Comment: What if there's 100 rows, with multiple rows with `NULL` values for the `MID`?...how does a row with `NULL` relate to the `SID` of another particular row? In a table with only 2 rows, it's obvious there's only one choice, but in a table with multiple rows, it's unclear what the logic is to define how two rows relate, when one row has a `NULL` `MID`.

Comment: See the operator `<=>` and functions `IFNULL` and `COALESCE`.